# CoffeeScript AngularJS documentation generator

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript, documentation-generation

I'm writing large application with CoffeeScript and AngularJS, and for now using Codo to build documentation. But it's too class-oriented and slightly uncomfortable for me. Doco and Coffeedoc not suitable too. Any suggestion what may I use?